# How do I add plots to separate figures using for loops in Julia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook, julia-plots

I am trying to create two separate figures for which I'd like to add plots to each using a for loop.

```
using Plots
gr()
Plots.theme(:juno, fmt = :png)

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [8,7,6,4]

pt1 = plot()
pt2 = plot(reuse = false)
for i in 1:5
    pt1 = plot!(x, i*y)
    pt2 = plot!(x, y/i, reuse = false)
end

display(pt1)
display(pt2)
```

I'd expect to get two figures as if I were doing them separately:
[image: Test of pt1]
[image: Test of pt2]

But instead what I get is two figures with all the plots for `pt1` and `pt2`.
[image: Actual results]

I tried looking into using `push!`, but the examples I found were making gifs, which is not what I'm trying to do. This seemed like the most straightforward way that should work, I must just be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plot!` can take plot handle as the first argument so it should be `plot!(pt1, x, i*y)`.

Here is the full corrected code:

```
using Plots
gr()
Plots.theme(:juno, fmt = :png)

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [8,7,6,4]

pt1 = plot()
pt2 = plot()
for i in 1:5
    plot!(pt1, x, i*y)
    plot!(pt2, x, y/i)
end

display(pt1)
display(pt2)
```

And here is the outcome:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why you need the `reuse` parameter here though.

Comment: Looks like you don't, I added it thinking that was the cause of my problems, but your solution without `reuse` works like I need it to!

Comment: So I remove it from my answer :)

Comment: Running your code in VSCode with my local installation of Julia (version 1.8.3) only returns one plot (and has the same functionality if reuse=false). I wonder if something broke this plotting functionality in Julia.

Comment: I checked on VS Code. If run from *.jl file this produces two plots in "Julia Plots" pane on two separate pages which seems fine . The question was however about Jupyter notebook running inside of VS Code - I can see this works fine - I am getting two plots one under the other (tested on 1.9.0 beta4 and lates VS Code)   so it seems nothing has changed.

Comment: The problem appears to be that if "Julia Use Plot Pane: Display Plots within VS Code" is checked then it does display two plots. However, if this is unchecked (and VS Code is restarted), only one plot is displayed (the second plot). I can reproduce this using `gr()` or `pyplot()` as the backend. The problem appears to occur on plotting windows outside of VS code. My testing is on version 1.8.3 on Windows 11.